# Django context processors and a Django project with mulitple applications

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project in which I have 4 applications. I am able to use custom processors (of course each app has its own context processor) to pass application level common variables to templates. But, when I need to pass the same context variable to all templates in all apps (variables common to all applications), I am just adding these context variables to each of the context processors individually. Is there any other way to pass a context variable to all templates in all apps, without having need to add it to each context processor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, when context processor introduces variable into context then this variable is available in all project's templates.

So you don't need to add variables to each of context processors, single processor will do the job.

Comment: I tried to put the context processor file at the root level of project folders, then I could only see the variables value in the default application templates, in others I was unable to see the value. Am I putting it to a wrong place.

Comment: Context processor is a plain python function that takes `request` and returns a `dict` of variables.  It can be placed anywhere.  The only thing you should do is to provide valid module/function name to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Comment: Usually I put project-wide context processors to the `projectname/context_processors.py` file alongside with the `settings.py`.  And then add `projectname.context_processors.my_processor` to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: Thank you, it was my mistake. The problem was that I was not returning request context in in most of my view responses and just testing with those views.